# HTML z-index for filter effects

Tags: html, css, filter, radio-button, z-index

I am using images for my radio button. I am aware that the CSS filter effects will impact the z-index properties.

I have created a sample fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/iambong/2kcvv3bL/1/

CSS:

```
.colour-black{background-image:url(https://s28.postimg.org/p585381cd/Colour_Black.png);}
.colour-blue{background-image:url(https://s24.postimg.org/clxbf89g5/Colour_Blue_suede.png);}
.colour-chestnut-brown{background-image:url(https://s23.postimg.org/swdj7nh6z/Colour_Chestnut_Brown.png);}

.colour-selector input{
position:relative;
z-index:2 !important;
overflow: hidden;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
border: none;
margin:0;padding:0;
-webkit-appearance:none;
   -moz-appearance:none;
        appearance:none;
 }

.colour-selector input:active +.colour-cc{opacity: 0.9; position:relative;    z-index:2;}
.colour-selector input:checked +.colour-cc{
position:relative; 
z-index:2;
-webkit-filter: none;
   -moz-filter: none;
        filter: none;
}

.colour-cc{
positon:relative;
  z-index:3 !important;
background-size:contain;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
display:inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 8px;
margin-bottom: 8px;
align: left;
width:100px;height:70px;
-webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
   -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
        transition: all 100ms ease-in;
-webkit-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
   -moz-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
        filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
}

.colour-cc:hover{
 positon:relative;
 z-index:10 !important;
 overflow: hidden;
 display:inline-block;
-webkit-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(0.9);
   -moz-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(0.9);
        filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(0.9);
-webkit-transform:scale(2.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-transform:scale(2.5); /* Firefox */
-ms-transform:scale(2.5); /* IE 9 */
-o-transform:scale(2.5); /* Opera */
 transform:scale(2.5);


}
```

HTML:

```
<p>Colour Selection</p>                  

 <div class="colour-selector"; style="position:relative; left:100px; top:50px; z-index:1;">

     <input id="colour-black" type="radio" name="properties[colour]" value="colour-black" style="position:relative; z-index:3;"/>
     <label class="colour-cc colour-black" for="colour-black"></label>
       <input id="colour-blue" type="radio" name="properties[colour]" value="colour-blue" style="position:relative; z-index:3;"/>
     <label class="colour-cc colour-blue" for="colour-blue"></label>
     <input id="colour-chestnut-brown" type="radio" name="properties[colour]" value="colour-chestnut-brown" style="position:relative; z-index:3;"/>
     <label class="colour-cc colour-chestnut-brown" for="colour-chestnut-brown"></label>

</div>
```

What I want:
What i hope to achieve is that on mouse-over (hover), the magnified image will be whole and not show parts of the neighbouring images

What is wrong now:
If you hover your mouse over the middle picture, the magnified image (using the transform scale in the CSS) shows parts of the neighbouring images

Thank you for any help!

Comment: The filters in .colour-cc create a new stacking context.  If you can live without the filter: brightness(1.2), you can simply remove the filter, add opacity:0.7, and it will work as expected.  Otherwise, you need to get each element to stack correctly.

Comment: hi walsh, yes i am aware that the filters create a new stacking context. i have tried your solution but it wouldnt work because opacity is a filter too hence there's still a stacking context

Answer (score 0):

use something like this:

```css
#nav{z-index:2}
#nav li{display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
    color:#fff;
   
    cursor:pointer;
height:50px;
  width:100px;
list-style-type:none;}

#nav ul li:nth-child(1){background:#b4b4b4;}
#nav ul li:nth-child(2){background:#cecece;}
#nav ul li:nth-child(3){background:#b4b4b4;}


#nav ul:hover li {
          transform: translateX(-24%);
    z-index:4;
}
#nav ul:hover li:hover {
 
          transform: scale(1.5);
          transition-duration: 0.18182s;
}
#nav li:hover ~ li {
          transform: translateX(24%);
    
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
    <li><p></p></li>
    <li><p></p></li>
    
    
    <li><p></p></li></ul>
    
    
          
        
    </div>
```

Comment: @Bill hope this helps you:)

Comment: thanks for the idea/help

I tried to implement your code but 

1) I'm looking to preserve the usage of the radio buttons, it's for a form, not sure how to use it in a html list format

please see the linked fiddle, there's a gap to the left and i couldnt click on the images now

2) could you kindly explain the 

".nav li:hover ~ li {
          transform: translateX(24%);
    
}"

part please, thanks!

[link] (https://jsfiddle.net/iambong/y8vyy9wk/1/)

Comment: @Bill ".nav li:hover ~ li { transform: translateX(24%); }" means the next siblings of li that is hovered will be translated in x direction by 24%.and please accept answer if it helped you:)

Comment: it works in displacing the elements but it doesnt allow me to keep the usage of radio buttons, could you help with that?

you can see the new fiddle
 [link] (jsfiddle.net/iambong/y8vyy9wk/1)

Comment: wats the role of radio buttons here

Comment: this is actually part of a form, i'm trying to collect user preference for the colours.

i am unable to create radio buttons in a html list

Comment: try something like this:

Comment: thanks for helping!

Previously, if you look at the original fiddle, i was using the radio buttons before hiding the buttons and using images for the labels to select.

What I need as mentioned before is for my client to select the colour images. However there is filter effect applied to the colour images hence i was looking for a z-index solution.

In your latest fiddle, the radio buttons are not part of the displacing solution